# curious thing happened in linux socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to build a server which can serve for many clients.

The server just do a simple job: get the input string from client and then change each letter to upper case.

But the problem is, when I try to shut down one client, for example, type "Ctrl-C", then my OS will be shut down suddenly.

I use the Ubuntu 10.10 and CentOS to test my program, but always the same problem.
Here's my source code:

```
/* client.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define MAXLINE 80
#define SERV_PORT 8000

int main (void)
{
    struct  sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char    buf[MAXLINE];
    int sockfd, n;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &servaddr.sin_addr);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    while (fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
        write(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf));
        n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE);
        if(n == 0) printf("Connect closed\n");
        else write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/* server */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define MAXLINE 80
#define SERV_PORT 8000

void sigchld_func (int signo) {
    wait(NULL);
}

int main (void)
{
    struct  sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char    buf[MAXLINE];
    char    str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int     listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t   cliaddr_len;
    int     n, i;
    pid_t   pid;

    signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_func);

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(listenfd, 20);

    printf("Accepting connections...\n");

    while (1) {
        cliaddr_len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &cliaddr_len);
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            perror("fork error!");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            close(connfd);
        } else {
            close(listenfd);
            while (1) {
                n = read(connfd, buf, MAXLINE);
                if (n <= 0) {
                    printf("Connection closed\n");
                    break;
                }
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, str, sizeof(str));
                printf("Received from %s at port %d\n", str, ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    buf[i] = toupper(buf[i]);
                write(connfd, buf, n);
            }
            close(connfd);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Er, the ***OS*** will shut down? Is it giving you any messages?

Comment: Without proper indentation, the code is much more difficult read than necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry.. The OS halted, I can do nothing but just shut down my computer

Comment: Saying halted is very different to shutdown...

Comment: Yes, I run both on the same machine by two terminal.

Comment: I do something like power-off.

Comment: You might consider adding more error checking to you system calls. This won't only help you when debugging.

Comment: You're right. I need to add more error checking. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server code is causing a fork bomb, and you're not seeing it properly because you're not checking the return value of `accept`.

The root cause is that in the child that reads/writes to the client, after the connection is closed, you're not either calling `exit` or returning out of main.

So the child process stays in the toplevel `while(1)` loop, tries to `accept` on `listenfd` (but you closed that one, which is good). `accept` fails, and you fork regardless. Tight loops of forks will slow down your computer, the scheduler can't deal with them properly (unless you have counter-measures in place).

So exit out of the program after `close(connfd)`, and add more error checking in your code.